I don't understand the process of updating the UI after submitting an answer / a comment
I have a server component that gets the initialAnswers, then it is sent through props in a client component that has an infinite scroll:
Page
├── AnswerForm (client comp)
│
└── AllAnswers (server comp)
    ├── getAnswers - server action (answers)
    ├── display totalAnswers
    └── AllAnswersInfiniteScroll initialAnswers={answers} (client comp)
        └── Votes (client comp)

If I display the answers in the server component, I can get the update with a revalidatePath() the server action, but it does not work in the client component.
So my question is, how do I get the client component to behave like a revalidatePath() in a server component?
The AllAnswers server component:
const AllAnswers = async ({ questionId, userId, totalAnswers, page, filter }: Props) => {
  const { answers, isNext } = await getAnswers({
    questionId,
    page: page ? +page : 1,
    sortBy: filter,
  });

  return (
    <div className='mt-11'>
      <div className='flex items-center justify-between'>
        <h3 className='primary-text-gradient'>{`${totalAnswers} ${totalAnswers === 1 ? 'Answer' : 'Answers'}`}</h3>

        <Filter filters={AnswerFilters} />
      </div>

      <AllAnswersInfiniteScroll
        initialAnswers={answers}
        questionId={questionId}
        userId={userId}
        isNext={isNext}
        filter={filter}
      />
    </div>
  );
}; 

The AllAnswersInifiteScroll client component:
const AllAnswersInfiniteScroll = ({
  initialAnswers,
  questionId,
  userId,
  filter,
  isNext,
}: Props) => {
  const [allAnswers, setAllAnswers] = useState(initialAnswers);
  const [isNextPage, setIsNextPage] = useState(isNext);

  const pageRef = useRef(1);

  const [ref, inView] = useInView();

  const loadMoreAnswers = async () => {
    const next = pageRef.current + 1;

    const { answers: newAnswers, isNext } = await getAnswers({
      questionId,
      page: next,
      sortBy: filter,
    });

    if (allAnswers?.length) {
      setAllAnswers((prevAnswers) => [...prevAnswers, ...newAnswers]);
      setIsNextPage(isNext);
      pageRef.current = next;
    }
  };

  const filterAnswers = async () => {
    pageRef.current = 1;

    const { answers: newAnswers, isNext } = await getAnswers({
      questionId,
      page: pageRef.current,
      sortBy: filter,
    });

    setAllAnswers(newAnswers);
    setIsNextPage(isNext);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    if (inView) {
      loadMoreAnswers();
    }
  }, [inView]);

  useEffect(() => {
    filterAnswers();
  }, [filter]);

  return (
    <>
        // Here I map the answers and display them.
        // In here I also have a Votes (client component)
    </>

This is what confuses me, and can't make it work with the votes / likes either:
The Votes and AnswerForm are both client components.
If I display the answers in the AllAnswers server component, I vote / like an answer -> it calls a server action that has revalidatepath() -> my vote / like answer is updated without me having to refresh the page.
But If I vote / like an answer, or I add a comment that is displayed after in a client component, revalidatePath() does not work?
The "display totalAnswers" works when I leave a comment / answer, that number is increased by 1, but I have to refresh the page to see the actual comment.
So if this increment is happening in the totalAnswers, it means that the cache is emptied, the answers are refetched from the db, correct? The totalNumber is refetched but the answers containing the new answers are not? 

ANYONE???????????????????
